# How to save and load game in javafx

Tags: java

I'm programming an easy version of blackjack without bets in javafx, and I'm almost done with every part but now I want to be able to save and load my BlackJack game but i have no idea how to do it. Can I save everything as txt file and then load it or is there any easy way of doing it? [my game layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb900.png)

Comment: there is good file format than txt .for example xml/json..etc

Comment: I still dont have any clue how to just make that freaking game to save and load! Anyone smart that can explain for a dumb ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a json serializer/deserializer like [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

[Define json structure](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) according to your data model and just serialize and deserialize your game objects to/from json file.

Example:

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

// Serialization
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);  

// ==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}

// Deserialization
BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);
// ==> obj2 is just like obj
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a file using `FileOutputStream` and read from a file using `FileInputStream`. I would use json format and have Jackson do all serialization but that's just me.

Comment: Currently doing a project with jackson, works like a charm. +1